# Driver not picking up onboard network device Intel I219-V

Tags: drivers, ethernet

I have a motherboard (PRIME Z690M-PLUS D4) with onboard Ethernet.

It shows up, but there is no driver specified, and the system labels it as UNCLAIMED.

```
$ sudo lshw -C Network -short
H/W path           Device          Class          Description
=============================================================
/0/100/1c.1/0      enp6s0          network        RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
/0/100/1f.6                        network        Ethernet Connection (17) I219-V
```

```
$ sudo inxi -N
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Ethernet I219-V driver: N/A
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8125 2.5GbE driver: r8169
```

And this is what `lspci -v` has to report:

```
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (17) I219-V (rev 11)
        DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Ethernet Connection (17) I219-V
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 19
        Memory at 85900000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Kernel modules: e1000e
```

So it has been paired with a kernel module?

From the kernel:

```
$ sudo journalctl -b | grep e1000
Sep 26 22:08:59 deca kernel: e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
Sep 26 22:08:59 deca kernel: e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
Sep 26 22:08:59 deca kernel: e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Sep 26 22:08:59 deca kernel: e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
Sep 26 22:08:59 deca kernel: e1000e: probe of 0000:00:1f.6 failed with error -2
```

In my network manager, only the realtek shows up, not the Intel ethernet.

Why is that happening?

Comment: Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man journalctl`.